# .net core app will not connect to postgres db during docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I've created an application that relies on a postgres db. My docker-compose looks like this.

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  imdb_id_service_volume:
    external:
      name: imdb_id_service_volume

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  postgres_imdb_id_db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - imdb_id_service_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app_network

  docker_imdb_id_service:
    image: docker_retrieve_data
    depends_on: 
      - "postgres_imdb_id_db"
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app_network
    ports: 
      - "5000:80"
```

My appsettings.json looks like this.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "PostgresConnection": "host=postgres_imdb_id_db; Username=postgres; Port=5432; Database=ImdbIds;"
  }
}
```

If I run the postgres container by itself and then run the application locally it works with localhost. Some other things I tried for my PostgresConnection in appsettings.json.

1. Using "Server" instead of "host".
2. using "docker.for.win.localhost" instead of container name
3. Using the gateway IP of the postgres container

Every tutorial I looked at seems straightforward but it's not working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was not rebuilding the docker-compose each time I was making a change. Using the container name worked.